# Can I add my Sina Weibo account to my phone?

Tags: accounts

I'm using **Sina Weibo** and I'd like to add my account to my phone. How do I add it if it is even possible?

I'm using Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: Just curious - is Sina Weibo very popular in Sweden?

Answer (score 2):

Sina Weibo accounts have been supported via the built in email+accounts since Windows Phone 8.0.

You can add via settings -> email+accounts -> add an account -> more

Comment: I believe that if you are running in a Chinese locale, you don't have to go to the "more" option, but I don't understand enough Chinese to verify

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add a Sina Weibo account to a Windows Phone.

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Press **email+accounts**
3. Press **add an account**
4. Tap **more**
5. Tap **Sina Weibo**
6. Follow the guide.